# documentation for annotation_processors (buck)

Tags: android, buck

Related to this ticket [Parameters for annotation processors are disabled and undocumented](https://github.com/facebook/buck/issues/85)

How do we use `annotation_processors` and `annotation_processor_deps` ?

Im using realm in a sample Android app and without the annotations (for *@RealmClass* and *@RealmMoudule*) the app crashes when built via buck (works normally if built via gradle).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles on this, the way to use annotation processors with [buckbuild](https://buckbuild.com) is:

- The `annotation_processors` is a immutable list of **processor** class. You can identify this by the package name used in *META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor* file, example: [Realm Processor](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm-annotations-processor/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor)
- The `annotation_processor_deps` is a immutable list of Rules (generally `prebuilt_jar` or `android_prebuilt_aar`) holding the annotation processor

A sample buck build file of a project that uses [Realm Java](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/)

```
prebuilt_jar(
  name = 'realm',
  binary_jar = 'libs/realm-android-0.82.2.jar'
)

android_library(
  name = 'main-lib',
  srcs = glob(['app/src/main/java/com/yourcompany/project/**/*.java']),
  deps = [
    ':supportv4',
    ':all-jars',
    ':build-config',
    ':res',
  ],
  annotation_processors = ['io.realm.processor.RealmProcessor'],
  annotation_processor_deps = [':realm']
)
```

Comment: We haven't documented it yet because we are considering changing the API (possibly something more like Bazel's java_plugin).